# how to calculate a batch file's runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file, runtime, batch-processing

I hope this is the place for more than just asking how to do something but also a place to ask what that how means. I'm wanting to add in a runtime calculator into a batch file. I've seen some examples of how to do that but I was hoping someone could explain what that all means. I'm very inexperience when it comes to batch scripting

Heres one explanation/example I found online: [Calculate How Long It Takes To Run A Batch File](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/calculate-how-long-it-takes-to-run-a-batch-file/)

And here's an example a coworker showed me.

```
@ECHO OFF
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\PATH1

set STARTTIME=%TIME%

rem here begins the command you want to measure
PROGRAM -r C:\PATH2\file.exetension
rem here ends the command you want to measure

set ENDTIME=%TIME%

rem output as time
echo STARTTIME: %STARTTIME%
echo ENDTIME: %ENDTIME%

rem convert STARTTIME and ENDTIME to centiseconds
set /A STARTTIME=(1%STARTTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%STARTTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%STARTTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%STARTTIME:~9,2%-100)
set /A ENDTIME=(1%ENDTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%ENDTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%ENDTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%ENDTIME:~9,2%-100)

rem calculating the duratyion is easy
set /A DURATION=%ENDTIME%-%STARTTIME%

rem we might have measured the time inbetween days
if %ENDTIME% LSS %STARTTIME% set set /A DURATION=%STARTTIME%-%ENDTIME%

rem now break the centiseconds down to hors, minutes, seconds and the remaining centiseconds
set /A DURATIONH=%DURATION% / 360000
set /A DURATIONM=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*360000) / 6000
set /A DURATIONS=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*360000 - %DURATIONM%*6000) / 100
set /A DURATIONHS=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*360000 - %DURATIONM%*6000 - %DURATIONS%*100)

rem some formatting
if %DURATIONH% LSS 10 set DURATIONH=0%DURATIONH%
if %DURATIONM% LSS 10 set DURATIONM=0%DURATIONM%
if %DURATIONS% LSS 10 set DURATIONS=0%DURATIONS%
if %DURATIONHS% LSS 10 set DURATIONHS=0%DURATIONHS%

rem outputing
echo STARTTIME: %STARTTIME% centiseconds
echo ENDTIME: %ENDTIME% centiseconds
echo DURATION: %DURATION% in centiseconds
echo %DURATIONH%:%DURATIONM%:%DURATIONS%,%DURATIONHS%

endlocal
```

An extra tidbit, I would love to have it in minutes or seconds vs centiseconds

EDIT BEGINS HERE:

I implemented both examples into my batch file (1 at a time of course) but when I tried to run them, the batch file made it to where the new additions should kick in and just closes. Any idea what is going on?

Also, any idea how I could write the `%DURATION%` variable to a sql table? I imagine I would use sqlcmd and use the sql insert into command but what parameters are needed?

Comment: The code is commented quite clearly. We're not really here to give you a line-by-line tutorial of how it works. What **specific question** (note that "question" is *singular*) do you have about the code you've posted?

Comment: I guess the stuff that is confusing me is implemeting this into another batch file. I'm very much a batch noobie and I'm still learning how they are read. From my understanding they are read line by line and so If I just slap this bit of code at the begining of the script it will record nothing or hardly any runtime. How does this get properly put into a script that will say for example run several simulations?

Also, what is happening in his formatting segment?

Comment: You put the code to test between the lines that read `the command you want to measure`. `%time%` is a system variable that contains the current time. starttime is set to the current time, then the program is run, then endtime is set to the current time, and then everything after that is math and formatting.

Comment: The code comment tells you exactly where *in this batch file* you insert the code you want to time, as @SomethingDark has pointed out. *This* doesn't get put into a script; you put *your script* into this one at the point the comment tells you you should. See `rem here begins the command you want to measure` and `rem here ends the command you want to measure`.

Comment: Okay after doing some seraching around, I think I need to implement the time stamp into the for loop in my other batch file. Otherwise its going to give me an overall time execution when I really want a time for each simulation

Comment: After your edit: How can we conceivably have any idea why the code you added doesn't work when we can't see the code you've added? You're turning this into a chameleon question (one that keeps changing and evolving and modifying it's colors).